# sudo apt-offline install not updating

Tags: 18.04, apt, upgrade

working with procedure [procedure](https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-or-update-ubuntu-offline-without-internet/)  to update Ubuntu 18.04 offline machine, the `sudo apt-offline install /path_to_downloaded_package_folder` do not apply any updates/upgrades.
The beginning of the massage I get is :

```
sudo apt-offline install ./updates_path/
No changelog available
(Y) Yes. Proceed with installation
(N) No, Abort.
(C) Display changelog
(?) Display this help message.
What would you like to do next:  (y, N, ?)y
Proceeding with installation
ERROR: Path for keyring is invalid: /etc/apt/trusted.gpg
gpgv: Signature made Mon 06 Jan 2020 08:17:27 AM MST
gpgv:                using RSA key 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
gpgv: Good signature from "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>"
gpgv: Signature made Mon 06 Jan 2020 08:18:52 AM MST
gpgv:                using RSA key 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
gpgv: Good signature from "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>"
gpgv: Signature made Mon 06 Jan 2020 08:18:25 AM MST
gpgv:                using RSA key 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
gpgv: Good signature from "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>"
gpgv: Signature made Thu 26 Apr 2018 05:38:40 PM MDT
gpgv:                using RSA key 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
gpgv: Good signature from "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>"
security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic-security_InRelease synced.
security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic-security_Release synced.
security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic-security_Release.gpg synced.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked that the file /etc/apt/trusted.gpg exists?

Comment: i see such a file with tilda:  `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg~`

Answer (score 5):

The apt-offline package no longer functions correctly based upon bugs reported in Debian and Ubuntu such as [Debian Bug #871656](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=871656) and [Ubuntu Bug #1848755](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt-offline/+bug/1848755).  Although you followed a posted procedure from a well-known site, Debian [pulled the package from testing upstream](https://tracker.debian.org/news/959448/apt-offline-removed-from-testing/) since it doesn't meet their standards.  Currently the development of apt is [breaking all offline installation solutions per Debian Bug #934657](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=934657) which has not been updated since August 2019.

The package author is waiting on changes in apt itself before the tool can get some re-writes accomplished to be able to function again.  This situation cannot be fixed presently.  You didn't do anything wrong, though.

Comment: do `sudo apt-key exportall | sudo gpg --no-default-keyring --import --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg` fix it, or I shouldn't use it?

Comment: @user1889297 Don’t do that.  Right now the package is broken and I probably should file a removal bug for Focal Fossa so it doesn’t make it into the next LTS.

Comment: Do you know of any other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

I found a problem and discovered a workaround. Shortcut to solution: do the procedure twice. More details and version problem correction bellow.

I was trying to do the procedure I see over the internet, but it also didn't upgrade the packages. I discovered you actually need to run `sudo apt upgrade` after the `apt-offline install`. But it didn't work either in the first attempt.

I did the following procedure:

```bash
# In the offline computer
$ sudo apt-offline set --update --upgrade ~/required-packages.sig
# Copy sig to the internet connected computer and
$ sudo apt-offline get --bundle ~/Downloads/downloaded-pckages.zip ./required-packages.sig
# Copy the zip to offline computer and
$ sudo apt-offline install ~/downloaded-pckages.zip
$ sudo apt upgrade
```

The last line tried to download packages from internet and it didn't work, since the computer is offline...

The problem was that even with options `--update` and `--upgrade`, the actual packages necessary for upgrading to newest packages were not downloaded. They were not inside the zip file. The `apt install` step was also updating the packages repositories (as you see the `synced` response), but not actually upgrading them.

Once the repositories where updated, I generated a new `.sig`, and downloaded the bundle again. This second time the newer packages upgrade files were downloaded and you find them in the zip file. After running the `apt install` with the new zip, you run `sudo apt upgrade` and it will work. It detects the downloaded packages and it won't try to connect to the internet.

So the workaround is actually doing the procedure twice. It seems the respositories need to be updated to generate a `.sig` asking for the upgrade packages.

There was still another problem. I am using **Ubuntu 22** and the default `sudo apt install apt-offline` installs **v1.8.4**, which fails to execute. There is a problem with the python threading function. So I downloaded **v1.8.5** deb package from [pkg.org repository for Ubuntu 23](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/23.10/ubuntu-universe-amd64/apt-offline_1.8.5-1_all.deb.html) and installed it manually with `sudo apt install apt-offline*.deb`. This version works normally. So my procedure was done with **v1.8.5** on **Ubuntu 22** for the connected computer, the offline computer is a **Ubuntu Server 22** I use for an embedded application that cannot connect to internet.